# Mac OS X Mountain Lion cannot share internet connection because of 802.1X protection

Tags: macos, internet-sharing, 802.1x

My notebook is connected on Ethernet using 802.1X. When I try to share the internet via Wifi I get the error message *Your Internet connection cannot be shared because its protected by 802.1X*

I dont have right now a option of not using a protected network. Is there a way to share the connection? I want to create an adhoc wifi network to test my devices.

Comment: There may be a way to do it, but it's not something I can recommend. 802.1X is is generally used in networks where security is important, and sharing your connection weakens the network's security. Talk to the people in charge of your network. If this is ok with them, they should be able to give you a better way to do it; if it's not ok with them, then DON"T DO IT!

Answer (score 3):

[This thread on discussions.apple.com](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/537453?tstart=0) presents an approach that involves twiddling the firewall and NAT rules in the terminal. I haven't tested that.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with Gordon. The 802.1X security measures are in place for a reason. You should contact your IT team to see if they have other options for you or if they can set up a guest network. In the absence of that, I would recommend getting a MiFi from your carrier or turning your smartphone into a wireless hotspot. If you have access to LTE, it may be faster than your office WiFi.

Comment: Why does this 'answer' gets a vote up? The question is how to share your OSX mountain lion 802.1X ethernet connection over WiFi. There is no mention of a mobile phone...

Comment: Agreed. There are many legitimate reasons for wanting to share an Internet connection. This "answer" does not actually answer the question, but instead provides contextless and naive security advice.

Answer (score 0):

Based my friends's case, this might be because your setting is wrong.

You need to set "Share your connection from Thunderbolt Ethernet" and "To computers using WIFI"

you may set in the opposite way